# TFS2017: Setting for temp query URL (message)

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

I upgraded from 2015.3 and now the pop-up message is missing the number of days; previously it was 90 days.

It's possible to fix the message?

[image]

Comment: I see this behavior too. I guess that you can create a bug on https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio and hope that it gets fixed for the next update.